# ionic : Master Detail returns only id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, master-detail

I'm running out of idea right now. Everything seems fine, but when Im trying to inherit master data into the details view nothing really shows when I consoled except for the id.

Console Output : `Object {id: "78"}`

Here's my code :

**Config**

```
.state('app.home', {
url: "/home",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
    controller: 'PostHomeCtrl'
  }
}})    

.state('app.posthome', {
url: "/home/:id",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/post.html',
    controller: 'PostDetailCtrl'
  }
}})
```

**Factory**

```
.factory('Posts', function($http){
var blogs = []; //Private Variable
return {
    GetBlog: function(){ 
        return $http.get('path/to/resources').then(function(response){
            blogs = response;
            return response;
        });
    },
    GetPost: function(postId){
        for(i=0;i<blogs.length;i++){
            if(blogs[i].id == postId){
                return blogs[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}})
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('PostHomeCtrl', function(Posts, $scope){
 Posts.GetBlog().then(function(blogs){
    $scope.blogs = blogs.data;
    console.log(blogs.data);
 });
})

.controller('PostDetailCtrl', function(Posts, $stateParams, $scope){
 var postId = $stateParams;
 $scope.blog = Posts.GetPost(postId);
 console.log(postId);
});
```

Comment: can you share the blogs data that you get after ajax call ? that you logged at PostHomeCtrl

Comment: @semirturgay nvm just figured it out, turns out my I forgot to add `.data` at my `blog = response` . So it becomes `blog=response.data` instead of `blog=response`. Thanks

Comment: If a problem is solved: Accept an answer, don't edit the title.

Answer (score 0):

nvm just figured it out, turns out my I forgot to add `.data` at my `blog = response` . So it becomes `blog=response.data` instead of `blog=response`. Thanks